# lifecycle_msgs/msg/state.hpp is missing by build ROS2 UR_Robot_DRIVER

Tags: ros, ros2, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening to all participants.
when i'm compiling the last state of the UR driver for ROS2, so i get a fatal error

```
workspace/install/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/system_interface.hpp:26:10
"fatal error: lifecycle_msgs/msg/state.hpp: No such file or directory26  #include "lifecycle_msgs/msg/state.hpp"
```

the package "ifecycle_msgs" is installed, and the Cmakelist contains "find_package(rclcpp_lifecycle REQUIRED)".

has someone already such experience done and how to make it fix and running???

thanks for any information about that

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393236/lifecycle_msgs/msg/state.hpp-is-missing-by-build-ros2-ur_robot_driver/) by [kolasha](https://answers.ros.org/users/87028/kolasha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to also depend on the `lifecycle_msgs` package. Add it to your `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` so it is found and the include directories are added to your compilation commands by CMake.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2021-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1